# I'm trying to create Comments in a post

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I tried to create comment in my post But I can't use

```
Posts.associate = (models) => {
      Posts.hasMany(models.Comments), {
          onDelete: "cascade",
      }
  }
```

I'm not sure if it's because I myself got the update. `"Sequelize.js"` is latest so I can't use this command.

I've checked and I can't find any errors.

If you know the correct command you can guide me.

i hope you can help me

models Posts:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Posts = sequelize.define("Posts", {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    postText: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });
    
  Posts.associate = (models) => {
      Posts.hasMany(models.Comments), {
          onDelete: "cascade",
      }
  }

  return Posts;
};
```

models Comments:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comments = sequelize.define("Comments", {
    commentBody: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  return Comments;
};
```

Comment: "the latest update prevents me from using this command".  The latest update of what?

Comment: I think it belongs to Sequelize.js.

Comment: Show the code where you register models and associations